# Where to find samples for latest ServiceStack release?

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am very new to ServiceStack. I just want to know the sample codes from this link (and Samples from Github) is still working with latest ServiceStack release?

http://www.servicestack.net/docs/ormlite/ormlite-overview

I encountered error at

```
    //Re-Create all table schemas:
    dbCmd.DropTable<OrderDetail>();
    dbCmd.DropTable<Order>();
    dbCmd.DropTable<Customer>();
    dbCmd.DropTable<Product>();
    dbCmd.DropTable<Employee>();

    dbCmd.CreateTable<Employee>();
    dbCmd.CreateTable<Product>();
    dbCmd.CreateTable<Customer>();
    dbCmd.CreateTable<Order>();
    dbCmd.CreateTable<OrderDetail>();
```

when I switched back to older dlls (3.7.9.0) that's fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those docs appear to be from 2011, and ServiceStack has had a new API (or two) since then. You'll be better off looking at github:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite

In this particular case, all methods that were added to `IDbCommand` have been moved to `IDbConnection`.

Comment: Thanks JimmiTh, I found out the same. ServiceStack examples are using the latest API.